# Check if the passed Parameter to a stored procedure exists in a list?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I am trying to find if the parameter passed to the stored procedure exists in a given list so that I can continue the process or raise an error. However, it is raising an error by default. How do I know what exactly is the problem in this case?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MySchema].[MyProcedure]
    (@MyParameter CHAR(10))
AS 
    IF (@MyParameter <> 'INSERT' OR 
        @MyParameter  <> 'UPDATE' OR 
        @MyParameter <> 'DELETE')
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Invalid parameter passed', 15, 1);
    END;

    UPDATE [MyTable]
    ....
    ..
```

And, here is how I am executing this:

```
EXEC [MySchema].[MyProcedure] @MyParameter = 'UPDATE';
```

I've tried even changing the code to

```
IF (LTRIM(RTRIM(@MyParameter)) <> 'INSERT' OR 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(@MyParameter))  <> 'UPDATE' OR 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(@MyParameter)) <> 'DELETE')
```

but it didn't help.

Environment: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Apr  9 2020 16:39:55   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you are using the logical `OR` operator. `OR` returns true if any one condition is true, so when you enter `UPDATE` the other 2 conditions are true - because its not `INSERT` or `DELETE`. Change `OR` to `AND` and your logic works. But even better use `NOT IN` as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MySchema].[MyProcedure]
(
    @MyParameter CHAR(10)
)
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @MyParameter NOT IN ('INSERT', 'UPDATE', 'DELETE')
    BEGIN
        --RAISERROR('Invalid Parameter passed', 15, 1);
        THROW 51000, 'Invalid Parameter passed', 1;
    END;

    UPDATE [MyTable]
    ...
END
```

NOTE: Its recommended to use [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) over `raiserror`.

Comment: Thanks Dale, that helped. I didn't use THROW earlier because it was showing syntax error on SSMS but it looks like it is a bug. The code still executes fine even though it shows syntax error.

Comment: Yip, SSMS has a bug there with regard to throw and semi-colons - well spotted.

Comment: Is there a way that could be reported somewhere on MS website just like the Azure stuff?